# Looking for arms race critical story book about dragons

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book when I was a kid in the late 90s, but it maybe wasn't for kids.

A boy gets transfered to another realm and I only remember they had a huge area of glass where some magicians had been fighting and they had used their magic to summon dragons and it went totally bad, all the earth melted to glass.

When the boy later comes home to his world, he sees a news report about new missle system called dragon that is supposed to solve some military problem. Think that was on the last page of the book.

Sorry, that is all I remember.

Answer (score 8):

Great, after posting I remembered which friend lent me the book, and it was in German, not English, sorry!!

The book was [Drachenfeuer](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/97215.Drachenfeuer) by Wolfgang Hohlbein and Heike Hohlbein. It would be translated as "Dragon Fire" in English, but I can't find anything with that name.

[image]

Comment: There don't appear to be any English translations of this book.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted.